# Check scheduled job status in SAP BODS

Tags: scheduler, hana, sap-data-services

I am new to BODS, At present I have configured a job to execute every 2 minutes to perform transaction from MySQL server and load into HANA tables.

But sometimes when the data volume in MySQL is too large to transform and load into HANA within 2 minutes, the job is still executing my next iteration for the same job starts which results in BODS failure.

My question is: is there is any option BODS to check for the execution status of the scheduled job between runs?

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a control/audit table to keep history of each run of bods job. The table should contain fields like `eExtractionStart`, `ExtractionEnd`, `EndTime` etc. And you need to make a change in the job, so that it reads status of previous run from this table before starting the load to Hana data flow. If previous run has not finished, the job can raise an exception.

Let me know if this has been helpful or if you need more information.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a recomended way to do this?